# How to use the current url of a mechanize object for parsing using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I want to use the mechanize library to login to a website and then click a couple of buttons to reach a certain web page that I want to parse using BeautifulSoup.

I have looked a couple of answers on Stack Overflow and I can use the mechanize library to login and click the buttons to reach the page that I want but then I am unable to parse that link using BeautifulSoup. This is my code :

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open(login page link)  # Url that contains signin form
br.select_form(nr=0)
br['username'] = "username" 
br['password'] = 'password'
result = br.submit().read()
for link in br.links():
    if "link1" in link.url:  
        to_follow = link
        break

br.follow_link(to_follow)
for link in br.links():
     if 'link2' in link.url: 
        to_follow = link
        break

br.follow_link(to_follow)
str = str(br.geturl())
page = requests.get(str)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
elements_list = soup.find(id_='content')
elements_list_items = elements_list.find_all('a')
for i in elements_list_items:
    print(i)
```

I get the following error code

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/test1/login.py", line 37, in 
>       for i in elements_list_items:
>   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Change to 3rd last line to `soup.find_all('a')` instead of `elements_list.find_all('a')`.

Comment: @InfectedDrake  but won't that search for <a> in the entire document instead of finding it within tags that have the id as content ?

Comment: Yes it would. Is it otherwise what you're looking for? Then of course the block didn't have the above mentioned what you're searching for, and hence it returns nonetype. Giving the HTML response of the site itself might help.

Comment: @InfectedDrake yes i am looking to search for <a> tags only within other tags that have the id 'content' . And I was further debugging this code and I found out that the the function `BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser') ` opens back the login page not the page that is currently there in to_follow . So I guess that is giving me the error.

Comment: @InfectedDrake how can I use the link there in to_follow as a parameter of the BeautifulSoup in order to parse it?

Comment: I am not quite familiar to the `mechanize` library since it is not being maintained anymore. But from your code, I can say that you need to assign a variable wherever you're doing `br.follow_link()`, and work with the variable in your next block of code.

Comment: @InfectedDrake so can i use anything instaed of `mechanize`

Comment: you can use the RoboBrowser library.

Comment: If anyone has the same question as me. After trying RoboBrowser I am using selenium as robobrowser doesn't support dynamic content like js and ajax.